# how to swap images like only one image display in one page,next image in next page just like windows phone gallery,in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am new to windows phone 8 development so any one can you please help me in getting the Original size images which is stored into the camera roll (sdcard) in windows phone. and how to swap images like only one  image display in one page,next image in next page just like  windows phone gallery.I want to develop app that capture images fro camera roll,but all images display same size here i use listbox & scrollviewer(can you provide simple code for this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Pivot Control and in its content load the image

```
 <phone:Pivot  x:Name="PivotAttachment"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding ObsDownloadedAttachments}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="48">
                <phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <Image Grid.Row="1" Source="{Binding DownloadedBitmap}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
                    <phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ImageUrl}"
                                   Foreground="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ThemeColorBrushConverter}}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
                <!--Pivot item one-->


                <!--Pivot item two-->

            </phone:Pivot>
```

Comment: Thanks,Can u provide simple code for above query..i was try but i do not complete these task until i have try to 24 hrs these task.

Comment: @user3024175 have u created collection of images u have kindly paste the data\

Comment: Thanks,but i was also try to paste my code in xaml file include <grid></grid> but not work,i have created app using dynamic list box,also i have set list box property ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" to scroll image but i have need to scroll like media library images(paging)where in list box collected all camera roll images &image property Source="{Binding}" to all images.how to swipe images swipe one by one

Comment: @user3024175 then you can easily set image as pivot item template

Comment: how to set multiple images one by one  where i was collected in all camera roll images into listbox,where i can add <list> box&<images> tag.to display images like media library in windows phone

Comment: @user3024175 in Pivot tag there is Pivot.ItemTemplate Tag

Comment: @user3024175    <DataTemplate x:Key="1">
            <Grid>
                <Image VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="TestImage" Grid.Row="1"
                       Visibility="{Binding ProgressDownload,Converter={StaticResource AttachmentPlaceHolderVisibilityConverter}}"
                       Source="/Images/imgPlaceholder.png" />
                <Image Grid.Row="1" Source="{Binding DownloadedBitmap}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>

Comment: @user3024175 use this template

Comment: Thanks for quick reply,But i have collected camera roll  images in to list box not use "source=path" property in image,in pivot not include list box,how i can display these images

Comment: @user3024175 you can bind image to source directly

Comment: how to bind directly source for camera roll images that are stored in local device(i.s. windows phone8),i have use media library and collect all camera roll images into bitmap list,where i try to use above code but emulator screen display System.Windows.DataTemplet error..

Comment: source={Binding bitmap}; bitmap = image u have collected

Comment: hi,all images getting,but same problem all images scrolling vertically insted paging one image at a time ,like media library swaping on by one horizontally.

Comment: can you paste screenshot?

Comment: .here i have using first pivot item include <phone:LongListSelector> followed by <Image  Source="{Binding}">

Comment: <phone:Pivot Title="MY APPLICATION"> <phone:PivotItem><phone:LongListSelector   Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding image1}" Name="listbox"
                  Grid.RowSpan="2">
                    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate > <DataTemplate>                            <StackPanelOrientation="Horizontal" Width="550" ><Image HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="image1"   Stretch="UniformToFill"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="{Binding}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Grid.Row="1" />

Comment: @user3024175 no no there is no need of LLS

Comment: Without LLS how to collect images & how display(swipe)images.is there any property to scrollviewer to enable paging like iphone

Comment: Finally,i got solution of my problem, as per your guideline.